# Dovecot LDA (deliver) and LDAP groups

Tags: postfix, ldap, dovecot, groups

I have a LDAP and a Dovecot running on my server, the Dovecot uses LDAP as userdb and authdb, postfix is using LDA (deliver) to deliver the mails to the user. Now I want to have group email addresses like group1@example.com. This group is in my ldap like this:

```
objectClass: extensibleObject
objectClass: groupOfUniqueNames
objectClass: top
cn: group1
uniqueMember: uid=user1,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
uniqueMember: uid=user2,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
(...)
mail: group1@example.com
```

How can I get my dovecot LDA to except emails sent to group1@example.com and then send the mail to the uniqueMembers of the group?

Thanks

Philip

Answer (score 2):

This is not the job of Dovecot (or it's LDA). This is the job of Postfix to expand the user. And therefore there are the [`virtual_alias_maps`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_alias_maps) that do the expanding/rewriting. Each expanded user will then get the mail as before.

You just have to set the virtual_alias_maps to get the mapping from LDAP as described [here](http://www.postfix.org/DATABASE_README.html#preparing), but you probably are familiar with that as you already get your normal users from LDAP.

Comment: Thanks, that helps for a start but I have two problems with it: First all mail: attributes will be used and not just the first and second: I get a "user not found" bounce from the server even though the mail gets delivered to all users.